# ssh publickey error

Tags: terminal, ssh

I have a MBP with 10.8.4 and a Mac minis server with 10.8.4. I set sshd to only allow publickey and it worked.

But now, I’m now sure why, it doesn’t work anymore. I always get

> publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic

I think, I not change anything. permissons seems right.

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited/checked

```
sudo vi /etc/ssd_config
```

for the GSSAPI options?

Same for your local ~/.ssh/config

```
GSSAPIAuthentication=no
```